# Deactivate HTTP access for ActiveMQ 5.16.2 web console

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ 5.16.2, and I would like to only give a secured access to the web console. Thus, I would like to either:

- Make a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.
- If a redirect is not possible then deactivate the HTTP access with port 8161.

Which files will I have to configure and how can I configure those changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to change `conf/jetty.xml`. To disable HTTP access comment out the `Connector` bean, and then to enable HTTPS access uncomment the `SecureConnector` bean, e.g.:

```xml
    <bean id="invokeConnectors" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="Server" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setConnectors" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <!--bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                    <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
                    <property name="host" value="#{systemProperties['jetty.host']}" />
                    <property name="port" value="#{systemProperties['jetty.port']}" />
                </bean-->
                <!--
                    Enable this connector if you wish to use https with web console
                -->
                <bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
                    <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
                        
                            <property name="keyStorePath" value="${activemq.conf}/broker.ks" />
                            <property name="keyStorePassword" value="password" />
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="port" value="8162" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

You'll want to supply your own SSL certificate. Just put your certificate in the `conf` directory and change the `keyStorePath` and `keyStorePassword` values appropriately, e.g.:

```xml
<property name="keyStorePath" value="${activemq.conf}/myCert.p12" />
<property name="keyStorePassword" value="myCertPassword" />
```